# Async signal or notification between processes on Windows

Tags: windows, asynchronous, signals

There are 2 processes running on Windows. They communicate with each other through named pipe. When one of them is ready to send a message, I want to notificate the other process asynchronously like signal on Linux so that the other process don't need to check for the pipe continously. Are there some similar methods like the signal mechanism on Windows or other way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct signal mechanism which conceptually works the same way does not exist (one *could* probably simulate it with a thread injection hack, but don't even think about that). It is not much of a problem, since you can do otherwise.

Every waitable kernel object which can take a *name* such as an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or a [semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be accessed by different processes.
You can `WaitForSingleObject` on the synchronization primitive until the other process signals it. That would be a Unix-like *readiness* notification mechanism (not quite as elegant, but to the same effect).

However, that isn't even necessary. Named pipes (not true for *anyonymous* pipes!) can be used with overlapped I/O. Which means you can use [`ReadFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to initiate a read from the pipe, and it will linger there in the background until it can complete.
You can think of this kind of I/O as "fire and forget". Your process continues running while the read operation is blocked. When the read operation completes, it signals an event or posts a completion message to a completion port (which you can query) or posts an asynchronous procedure call ("APC", a more fancy name for "callback") to the thread that originally called it. That's as close to a "signal" as you can get under Windows.
Unluckily, APCs don't *quite* work as one would wish, since they only execute at well-defined points (when a thread is in an "alertable wait state", which you must do *explicitly* by setting the altertable flag in a wait function or calling `NtTestAlert`).
The likely reasoning why the Windows designers made it that way that this is "safer", but it is also more annoying from an usability point of view. Alas, that is how it works.

Note that the overlapped I/O model is the exact opposite of the readiness notification system under e.g. Linux. Rather than asking the OS whether a descriptor is *ready* to be read, you tell the OS to read it, and you can have yourself be notified (or verify) whether this has *completed*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I find WaitForSingleObject will block current process. But in my process, I don't want the process to be blocked, instead it will continuously run a loop. And I don't want to check for the pipe in each loop. That's why I need a async way to notify the process.

Comment: Then overlapped `ReadFileEx` with a callback is your only option. You still need to "check" for the callback to be called since user-level APCs are only called while your thread is in an alertable wait state, but you can usually coalesce this with a "routine" call that you do anyway such as `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, or you can just call `NtTestAlert` to fire all pending APCs once per iteration (or once every X iterations), which is very fast. Unluckily, you can's send signals under Windows (you can send _messages_, but that's not the same, messages too must be polled).